# Google Place API autocomplete error handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-api

I managed to add the autocomplete feature for input and everything is working how it's supposed to.
The issue comes when for instance the API key is restricted: when I start entering a location, the app realizes that the Maps API is wrong or unavailable, etc. and greys out the input which stops me from typing a location.

I'm trying to understand how to render the `<Script />` component only if it works properly.

Here are `DisplaySearchBar.js` where the `<Script />` component is

```
const DisplaySearchBar = ({
  renderSortByOptions,
  onSubmit,
  where,
  handleChange,
  what,
  handleScriptLoad,
}) => {
  const restContext = useContext(RestContext);

  const { restaurants, clearSearch } = restContext;

  const googleUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY}&libraries=places`;

  return (
    <section className="searchBar">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="searchBar-form">
        <legend className="title">
          <Fade left>
            <h1>Where are you going to eat tonight?</h1>
          </Fade>
        </legend>
        <Fade>
          <fieldset className="searchBar-input">
            <Script url={googleUrl} onLoad={handleScriptLoad} />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="where"
              placeholder="Where do you want to eat?"
              value={where}
              onChange={handleChange}
              id="autocomplete"
            />

            <input
              type="text"
              name="what"
              placeholder="What do you want to eat?"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={what}
            />
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset className="searchBar-submit">
            <input
              className="myButton button"
              type="submit"
              name="submit"
              value="Search"
            ></input>

            {restaurants.length > 0 && (
              <button className="clearButton button" onClick={clearSearch}>
                Clear
              </button>
            )}
          </fieldset>
        </Fade>
      </form>
      <article className="searchBar-sort-options">
        <Fade>
          <ul>{renderSortByOptions()}</ul>
        </Fade>
      </article>
    </section>
  );
};
```

And `Search.js` where the function `handleScriptLoad()` is

```
const Search = () => {
  const restContext = useContext(RestContext);
  

  const [where, setWhere] = useState("");
  const [what, setWhat] = useState("");
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("best_match");

  const sortByOptions = {
    "Best Match": "best_match",
    "Highest Rated": "rating",
    "Most Reviewed": "review_count",
  };

  let autocomplete;

  // give active class to option selected
  const getSortByClass = (sortByOption) => {
    if (sortBy === sortByOption) {
      return "active";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  // set the state of a sorting option
  const handleSortByChange = (sortByOption) => {
    setSortBy(sortByOption);
  };

  //handle input changes
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "what") {
      setWhat(e.target.value);
    } else if (e.target.name === "where") {
      setWhere(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (where && what) {
      restContext.getRestaurants({ where, what, sortBy });

      setWhere("");
      setWhat("");
      setSortBy("best_match");
    } else {
      restContext.setAlert("Please fill all the inputs", "error");
    }
  };

  // displays sort options
  const renderSortByOptions = () => {
    return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map((sortByOption) => {
      let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
      return (
        <li
          className={getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)}
          key={sortByOptionValue}
          onClick={() => handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue)}
        >
          {sortByOption}
        </li>
      );
    });
  };

  // google suggestion

  const handleScriptLoad = () => {
    const options = {
      types: ["(cities)"],
    }; // To disable any eslint 'google not defined' errors

    // Initialize Google Autocomplete
    /*global google*/ 
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
      options
    );

    // address.
    autocomplete.setFields(["address_components", "formatted_address"]);

    // Fire Event when a suggested name is selected
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", handlePlaceSelect);
  };

  const handlePlaceSelect = () => {
    // Extract City From Address Object
    const addressObject = autocomplete.getPlace();
    const address = addressObject.address_components;

    // Check if address is valid
    if (address) {
      // Set State
      setWhere(address[0].long_name);
    }
  };

  return (
    <DisplaySearchBar
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      handleChange={handleChange}
      renderSortByOptions={renderSortByOptions}
      where={where}
      what={what}
      handleScriptLoad={handleScriptLoad}
    />
  );
};
```

Thanks for your help!